# php output txt files with record limits plus grouped by unique county names

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

When I ouput these txt files, I am trying to group them by unique county with a count limitation per county file. For example, let's say the query returns 2 unique counties in this accessable result field: `$row['county_txt']`.. Let's say I set the `$per_file` limitation to 2500. I have the script working now with the per_file etc but not with the counties grouping. Below is somewhat of a mash of where I am at. Thanks for any guidance in helping me resolve this.

**Output examples:**

---

Green County - Total Green county results 2900 output would be 2 files.

*Output files would be:*

Green-#1-20130627-2500.txt
Green-#2-20130627-400.txt

---

Red County - Total Red county results 12650 output would be 5 files.

*Output files would be:*

Red-#1-20130627-2500.txt
Red-#2-20130627-2500.txt
Red-#3-20130627-2500.txt
Red-#4-20130627-2500.txt
Red-#5-20130627-150.txt

---

```
... // earlier part of script
     // Functions I've been attempting

$county[] = $row['county_txt'];

function unique_county() {
    foreach($county as $unq_cnty) {
    echo $unq_cnty;
return $unq_cnty;
}

} 

 function get_unique_county() {
    $column = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $column[] = array_unique($row['county_txt']);
    echo $column;
}
}

get_unique_county();

$file_count = 1;
$recs = 0;
$per_file = 2500;
$footer = "FOOTER";
$default_contents = $contents = array("BODY CONTENT TOP");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $line = "...";
    $contents[] = $line; // Each array element will be a line in the text file
    $i++;
    $recs++;

    if ($county == $unq_cnty && $i == $per_file) {
    $contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
    file_put_contents($unq_county . "-#" . $file_count .  "-" . date('Y') . "-" . $recs .  '.txt', implode("\r\n", $contents));
        $i = 0;
        $recs = 0;
        $contents = $default_contents;
        $file_count++;
    } // End of if()
} // End of while()
```

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `echo $column` in the get_unique_county` call... all you'd be doing is outputing `Array`, `Array`, `Array`, etc... plus the function doesn't return anything, so it's rather pointless.

Comment: Marc B, I've been up for a few days working on this and kinda lost track of up and down. You are correct I'll I've been outputting was "Array".. But I tried to add the function function unique_county() directly in the output and it returned errors. The script is confused no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter, and then be able to reset it (upon resetting it, you save the file).

Example (untested, example only):

```
<?php
$rowCounter = 0;
$fileCounter = 1;
$startID = md5(microtime(1));
$fp = fopen("{$startID}.txt", "w");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $rowCounter++;
  fwrite($fp, $row['county_txt']."\r\n");
  if($rowCounter == 2500) {
    fclose($fp);
    if($startID) {
      rename("{$startID}.txt", "Red-#{$fileCounter}-".date("Ymd")."-{$rowCounter}.txt");
      $startID = md5(microtime(1));
    }
    $fp = fopen("{$startID}.txt", "w");
    $rowCounter = 0;
    $fileCounter++;
  }
}
// Save last file
fclose($fp);
rename("{$startID}.txt", "Red-#{$fileCounter}-".date("Ymd")."-{$rowCounter}.txt");
?>
```

On that note, don't use `mysql_*` functions. Instead, use `mysqli` at the very least, or `PDO`.

Comment: Rob W, thanks for the suggestions. The "Red" and "Green" are also variables as they are generated from the query results. All output files are grouped by County name limited to 2500 records per file. And of course if there was less than 2500 for any given county there would only be one file.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here, but it seems you are making things way harder than need be.  In essence, it seems that you need to work with a two-dimensional array.  So why not just query the database and read the data into a 2-D array right off the bat rather than jump through all these extra hoops (i.e. functions to determine unique array values and such)?

So you code might look something like this:

```
$county_array = array()

while ($row = [YOUR DATABASE ROW FETCHING MECHANISM HERE]) {
    $county_array[$row['county_name']][] = $row; // you can change $row here to whatever data you actually need to store.
}

$limit = 2500;
foreach ($county_array as $county_name => $county_array) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($county_array as $item) {
        $temp_array[] = $item;
        $i++;
        if ($i === $limit) {
            // we reached file limit, so write it to file code omitted for this
            $temp_array = array();
            $i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (count($temp_array) > 0) {
        // there are still items in temp array so write them to file code omitted for this
    }
}
```

If you actually order by country name in your query and detect for changes to the value when reading county names out (and thus starting a new file), you could actually write directly into files in your loop that reads from the DB saving yourself memory overhead.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am fiddling with your idea to see if I can get things working properly. To answer your question "Note really sure what you are trying to do here" - basically what I am trying to do is echo records into a text file, each text file a county (but depending on the amount of records there could be more than one text file per county).